# Ошибка при создании папки на сервере

Tags: python, django

Разместил на сервере ubuntu проект. Пытаюсь создать папку на сервере следующим кодом

```
def check_image(self, user):
    new_folder = os.path.join('media', 'mu_folder', f'user_{user}')
    try:
        path = os.mkdir(new_folder)
    except Exception as e :
        print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % e)

    return new_folder
```

Однако получаю ошибку

> path = os.mkdir(new_folder)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'media/mu_folder/user_1'

Пытался так же указать такой вариант

```
def check_folder(self, user):
    new_folder = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'media', 'mu_folder', f'user_{user}')
    try:
        path = os.mkdir(new_folder)
    except Exception as e :
        print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % e)

    return new_folder
```

файл setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
DEFAULT_IMG = (STATIC_URL + 'no_image.png')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Однако получал тоже ошибку

> path = os.mkdir(new_folder)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'root/project/projectfolder/media/mu_folder/user_1'

В в корневом файле urls.py указывал два варианта. в файле urls.py самого проекта(который вызывает создание папки) не указывал ниже указанные варианты.

1 вариант

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

2 вариант

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Подскажите, из-за чего может не создаваться папка на сервере.

Comment: Так вам же python сказал в чём ошибка и проблема, что вы ещё хотите?

Comment: Что бы он создал папку.

Comment: Как он должен создать папку, если это невозможно?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы объяснить мне глупому, почему это невозможно. Если на локальной машине это работает, а на сервере нет ?

Comment: Добавил ответ. До этого у вас работало, потому что была другая ОС

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы используете `os.makedir('media/mu_folder/user_1')`, то python пытается создать директорию `user_1` по пути `media/mu_folder`. Если путь `media/mu_folder` не существует, то выбрасывается исключение, которое вы сейчас видите.

Если вы хотите, чтобы python сам автоматически создавал каталоги `media` и `mu_folder`, а не выбрасывал исключение используйте `os.makedirs`